# iOS: how to stop text animation in partial curl

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm using a partial curl modal in my iOS application. Please see this video:
http://vimeo.com/38643030

During the partial curl transition, the text in the *round rect buttons* is moving too. How can I stop this?

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to call the animation and to set up the buttons?

Comment: Actually I'm not using any code. It is done using my storyboard with a seque.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` in the `-viewDidLoad` implementation for the view controller that's being shown via the curl animation. This makes the buttons & their contents lay out once before the animation starts instead of trying to do its layout (and redo it as things change around it) during the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to rickster's answer, I had a similar problem with a UITableViewController and it was necessary to add

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
```

in the -viewDidLoad. Neither of the above statements worked on their own.