# Partial curl transition causes control resize

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

Within an iOS 5 (storyboard-based) app I am presenting a modal view controller, using the partial curl transition. When the transition is taking place, and the modal view controller is being revealed, I can see that some controls on the modal view controller (primarily UIButtons and UISegmentedControls) are being resized. They seem to be animating from a smaller size to their proper, fully defined size. I am unsure why this is happening and it looks pretty bad from a user's point of view. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

from [iOS: how to stop text animation in partial curl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9763558/1409904):

Put [self.view layoutIfNeeded] in the -viewDidLoad implementation for the view controller that's being shown via the curl animation. This makes the buttons & their contents lay out once before the animation starts instead of trying to do its layout (and redo it as things change around it) during the animation.