# presentModalViewController with modalTransitionStyle causing all controls in XIB to "animate in"

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have an iPhone App (Add Reminder to Calendar) where the preferences screen is presented via the following code:

```
-(IBAction) showPreferences {   
    preferencesViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
    [self presentModalViewController:preferencesViewController animated:YES];
}
```

This curls back the "main" screen to reveal the preferencesViewController, as shown here:

[image: this screenshot]

Both the main view controller and the preferencesViewControllers are laid out via XIBs.

The problem is that any and all the input elements (UISegmentedControls, UIButtons, etc) are "animated in" the first time the view is presented - they "grow" from left to right.  (You can see this by [installing the app - apologies for the plug](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/add-reminder-to-calendar/id386531068?mt=8)).  Subsequent returns to this screen do not exhibit this problem.

If I pass in animated:NO instead, the preferencesViewController is never shown - to get it to appear, I must omit the modalTransitionStyle as well, and when I do that, the transition from one screen to the other is quite jarring.

This isn't a deal breaker, but it's been bugging me for awhile -- is there any way I can either "force" the initial placement of the elements in my XIB and prevent them being "animated in", while still getting the benefit of the animated-in modal view controller with the fancy page curl?

Comment: Post the code where the segmented controls are being initialized and added.

Comment: The values are "statically defined" (hardcoded) in the XIB (via Interface Builder).  The selectedIndex is a one-liner:  segCapitalization.selectedSegmentIndex = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"autocapitalizationType"];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741052).

You need to force view layout to happen before the animation starts. This is probably a bug; file those Radars!