# Rogue Animation of UISegmentedControl under Partial Curl

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, ios5

I have a view controller with a button that activates a Storyboard Modal Segue with the Partial Curl transition.

On the view controller that is revealed, I have a `UISegmentedControl`.

Lastly I have reduced the font size of the `UISegmentedControl`.

When the button is pressed, the page curls to reveal the segmented control - during the curl animation, you can clearly see the segmented control animate from zero width out to the actual width - it looks very odd and messy, and I can't figure out why this happens!

I was able to reproduce the effect as follows:

- Create single view project
- Add second view controller to the storyboard
- Add a `UIButton` to the first view controller
- Add a `UISegmentedControl` to the new view controller
- Link the button to the second view with a Partial Curl Modal Segue
- Add a class file to the project, inherited from UIViewController
- Add an `IBOutlet` for the segmented control to the new class
- Link the second view controller to the new class and the segmented
  control to the outlet
- In `viewDidLoad:` in the new class add:

  ```
  [segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14] forKey:UITextAttributeFont] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  ```

A similar  effect is also seen if the curl is allowed to open in landscape

Comment: This questions seems to be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741052/ios-how-to-stop-text-animation-in-partial-curl. Have you tried adding `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` to the `-viewDidLoad` implementation?

Comment: Also, I reproduced all of your steps and didn't get this problem. Which version of XCode are your using? What are your base SDK and deployment target? In the line you put in your `viewDidLoad:`, you directly call `segmentedControl`, no `self.segmentedControl`or `_segmentedControl`, is that because you directly declare the ivar ?

Comment: give us the entire viewDidLoad please. Not sure what is happening from the information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I have came across something similar. Try changing the `selectedSegmentIndex` right before the curl (you can set it to -1 to deselect) to force the control to have width.